# WP E-Commerce Custom Meta > Serialized array

Tags: custom-field, metabox, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have an issue where I am adding custom meta to my products. Everything works fine until I update my product.

This is before:
[image]

This is after update:
[image]

I am thinking it has something to with how it is pulling the data from the database. Anyone else have this problem before?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Anyone know why it is printing serialized values? Or where to look?

Comment: I'm guessing no one has had this problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by the addition of the WP "Custom Fields" metabox to the product post type.